# How to get all pickled data

Tags: python, pickle

I have a pickled file with some data structures. I don't know the exact amount and types of elements. How to get all objects into a dict or a list?
The question is how to iterate through the file not knowing the number of entries?
Do all objects are stored as strings?
EDIT: I'm using such code to save data in file:

```
import pickle

def _save(_file, *_obj):
    with open(_file, 'w') as f:
        for obj in _obj:
            pickle.dump(obj, f)
```

the only solution I see right now is to store the number of objects as a first entry. read it, then read everything else.

I can easily unpickle data that way:

```
list_data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dict_data = {1:'a', 2:'b'}
tuple_data = (1, 2, 3)

_save('my_pickle.pckl', list_data, dict_data, tuple_data)
with open('my_pickle.pckl', 'r') as f:
    item1 = pickle.load(f)
    print item1
    item2 = pickle.load(f)
    print item2
    item3 = pickle.load(f)
    print item3
```

this gives me what I want... but I need to do it in a loop

Comment: @MartijnPieters pickle.load() returns one object at a time... am I wrong?

Comment: Ah yes, it'll read until it comes to the end of the object pickled. Unless you added extra information to the pickle file, there is no way of knowing how many pickles it holds. `pickle.save()` doesn't store that information because it cannot know how many times you'll add pickles to the file.

Comment: As I understand, you can pickle/unpickle just one single object, not several. Now the pickled object might (and probably will) contain other objects nested in (referenced by) it, which will be automatically pickled and unpickled with it, but at the base of the hierarchy, there's only one "main" object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add all your objects to a list and then do whatever you prefer with them.

```
with open(pickle_file) as f:
    unpickled = []
    while True:
        try:
            unpickled.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
```

Comment: that's quit nice, but it is a pity, I cannot do it easier. This function will be called pretty often, and it is not good to catch Exceptions every time... but I don't see any other solution right now. Thank you.

Comment: @oleg.foreigner I agree it's not optimal, but I have yet to find a better way.

Comment: I wonder why there is no built-in method to get the number of entries.

Comment: @oleg.foreigner A built-in method would have to do the same (process every object and stop at EOF).

Comment: @JanneKarila why? I thought pickle objects have there own format, not just serialized data structures... but maybe I'm wrong. :)

Comment: It would be *awesome* if the builtin `iter(func, sentinel)` would accept exceptions as the sentinel value (there's a hack in [itertools examples](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html) for this if you care, look for `def iter_except`). Then you could say `unpickled = list(iter_except(lambda: pickle.load(f), EOFError)`. It does exactly the same thing as in my answer and is just syntactic sugar but look at that sexy bastard.

Comment: @oleg.foreigner Each `dump` outputs an object to the output stream. You get a sequential file, not a database. Look into the `shelve` module for a simple db of pickled objects.